# Query: COUNT in Access To Only Count Unique Values

Tags: ms-access

I have a table like so:

```
Customer  Purchase Date  Product
Frank     7/28/2015      Hammer 
Bob       7/29/2015      Shovel 
Bob       7/29/2015      Pickaxe 
Bill      7/30/2015      Pliers
```

The Purchase Date field records a new entry for every purchase.  So, if in one visit a customer purchases four items, my database creates four entries each with the same date.

I'm trying to write a query that displays the numbers of visits for each customer.  Output like so:

```
Frank  1
Bob    1
Bill   1
```

But when I use the `COUNT` function on the date in my query, it returns:

```
Frank  1
Bob    2
Bill   1
```

I want my query to only count unique dates, but the `COUNT` function doesn't work.  Everywhere I read, it also says that the SQL `COUNT (Distinct)` doesn't work in Access.  Access help says that if I set the Query Properties to Unique Values "Yes", it should only return unique values, but it doesn't work.  I tried Unique Record "Yes" also, but that didn't work either.

Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Cust, count(cust) as CustomerCount
from (Select Distinct Table1.Customer as cust, Table1.PurchaseDate
from Table1)
group by cust
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the opposite?

    from (Select Distinct Table.PurchaseDate...)?

Comment: You can have it as:  from ( Select Distinct Table1.PurchaseDate, Table1.Customer as cust from Table1 ).  Distinct will "look at" the entire row that is returned and only allow distinct rows to return.